# How can I "chain-load" grub from systemd-boot

Tags: grub2, systemd-boot

So in the process of getting systemd-boot working on one partition, which is its own install, and having another install in parallel which is using grub, I'd like to make systemd-boot, boot to grub as well. I'm using Manjaro, so it installed grub into EFI, but `systemd-boot install` doesn't seem to pick it up.

P.S. I know chainloading is a grub term, and that systemd-boot isn't really chainloading, as it's not a bootloader, technically, but I'm lacking a better term.

Comment: Actually, **systemd-boot** is *only* a bootloader. For now, can you select either option from the BIOS boot menu?

Comment: @ajgringo619 yes, I can

Comment: In theory, this *should* be doable. Somehow it can auto-detect and chain-load a Windows 10 bootloader, so why not **grub**?

Comment: @ajgringo619 right?

Comment: I've moved all of my Linux systems to **systemd-boot**; not a grub fan in the slightest. Next distro I install, I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this ended up being way easier than I thought. Using Debian 10.x XFCE as my base OS, I got it up and running. Next, I installed **systemd-boot** and verified the new boot entries with **efibootmgr**. After rebooting, I then proceeded to setup **systemd-boot** for Debian:

```
/boot/efi/loader/loader.conf
timeout 10
console-mode auto
editor yes

random-seed-mode with-system-token
```

Next, the entry for the OS:

```
/boot/efi/loader/entries/debian-10.conf
title   Debian 10 (testing)
linux   /Debian-10/vmlinuz-4.19.0-17-amd64
initrd  /Debian-10/initrd.img-4.19.0-17-amd64
options root=UUID=207c7201-34a2-41c9-8bff-191cac5a0378 rootflags=subvol=/ resume=UUID=031046e5-7788-43a4-88c6-18b7c08fe55a
```

Now for the easiest part - the entry for grub:

```
/boot/efi/loader/entries/grub.conf
title   Grub
linux   /EFI/debian/shimx64.efi
```

Lastly, I removed the entry for grub with **efibootmgr**:
`sudo efibootmgr -b 0004 -B` (your entry number will vary)

Reboot and you should see the (2) entries. Now, I would predict that on an update of grub that it will put its boot entry back into EFI, but I can't be sure if it will be the new default or not. Maybe it would be best to leave the entry (since it's already a secondary boot option).

Comment: looks like I forgot to leave a comment, for some reason when booting it was having trouble finding some /boot/... file. I'm not entirely certain why. I think it didn't actually know where to find /boot/ for grub, even though I re-installed grub just before I installed systemd-bootloader. But to be honest. I got regular boot working with systemd boot, so I'm not going to worry about it.

Comment: No biggie - I was just happy for the challenge. Since I've converted all of my (systemd) VMs to systemd-boot, it's nice to know that I don't have to get rid of GRUB right away.